# PHP file in Codeigniter does not update CSS and JS changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a project with Codeigniter that worked very well. I linked my CSS and JS files in my PHP documents and all worked fine. But now I see that it does not recognize the changes I made to the scripts. For example, I change the Background color in a class but it still show the old color, and same with JS, I change the content of a string but it still show old content. But when I link the same scripts to a HTML document, the work correctly and apply the changes. I'm so confused, I don't know why this happen, it's very strange.

PD: I'm using bootstrap and all my Scripts are at the end of the body tag

Comment: Could you add some examples. It does sound like a caching issue. Does this also happen on other browsers? Or does it show any different behavior.

Comment: Did you set your base url. also you may need to press control f5 hard refresh.

Comment: Ok When developing and making lots of changes, SHIFT-F5 or Control+Shift+R will reload the page ignoring the cached content (as opposed to F5 or Control+R. This was a very helpful trick when I encountered the same thing while I was making changes to css files in particular.

Comment: If you are behind a firewall like cloudfare, it will take time for your changes to take effect

Answer (score 3):

Try clear browser cache.

Try open your project on another browser.

Try clear CodeIgniter cache ( if activated ).

Share your main templates  ( how you build HEAD section for instance )

Put timestamps at the end of your main .css files or .js files like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/your-css-file.css?<?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>" />
```

... in order to load always your latest css source.

Answer (score 1):

Use following lines in your head tag

Also, put timestamp with your CSS files.

Comment: <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">